# How to GET and POST requests separately with HttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm using HttpRequestHandler to inject Spring beans into Servlets:

```
@Component("myServlet")
public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
```

HttpServlet has separate methods doGet, doPost etc for different request methods.
But HttpRequestHandler has only one:

```
    public void handleRequest (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

So how to handle GET and POST requests in this method separately? I need to have different logic for different request methods.

**UPDATE:**
Also I have a question: is there possibility to restrict handleRequest method to support only POST requests by configuration and to sendHTTP Error 405 automatically for other requests?

Comment: I don't do Spring, so I'm not sure about the canonical Spring approach, but did it occur to you that you can just check `req.getMethod()`?

Answer (score 4):

The [HttpServletRequest provides the method getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29)

> Returns the name of the HTTP method with which this request was made, for example, GET, POST, or PUT. Same as the value of the CGI variable REQUEST_METHOD.

Comment: Thanks. Also I have a question, is there possibility to restrict handleRequest method to support only POST requests by configuration and to sendHTTP Error 405 automatically?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void handleRequest (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{       
   if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
     //GET BODY
   }
   else if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
     //POST BODY
   }    
}
```